# Есть ли что-то типа EQUALS в Catch c++?

Tags: c++, catch-unit-test

Ситуация такая, есть класс, в котором перегружены операторы сложения и равенства, нужно написать юнит-тесты к этому классу (например, `c1 + c2 == c3`, где `c1`, `c2`, `c3` - объекты класса). Вопрос: как это сделать?

Знаю, что в *VS* используют `AreEqual` для таких целей, есть ли здесь что-то такое и как решить проблему? Использование `REQUIRE` и `REQUIRE_THAT` порождает ошибки.

Например: 
есть класс ComplexNum
В нём перегружены операторы следующим образом:

```
ComplexNum ComplexNum::operator + (const ComplexNum &comp) {
    ComplexNum temp;

    temp.re = this->re + comp.re;
    temp.im = this->im + comp.im;

    return temp;
}

bool ComplexNum::operator == (const ComplexNum &comp) {

    return this->re == comp.re && this->im == comp.im;
}
```

Мы имеем объекты

```
ComplexNum c1(2, 3);
ComplexNum c2(-8, 7);
ComplexNum c3(-6, 10);
```

И нужно протестировать на верность равенства, следующее выражение, например, вызовет ошибку. Как это сделать правильно?

```
REQUIRE((c1 + c2)== c3);
```

Comment: Добавьте код, порождающий ошибки, для демонстрации [mcve].

Comment: Определитесь, используете вы cpp unit test или все же catch. Приведите минимальный пример и полный лог сборки с ошибкой.

Comment: Приведите текст ошибок.

Comment: Ошибки вот на скриншоте: http://prntscr.com/lcjbkg

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Проблема заключается в том, что Ваш `operator==` неконстантный, что, в принципе, некорректно, но приемлемо. Тем не менее, Catch используется переданные аргументы как ссылки на константные объекты, в результате чего он требует от `operator==` быть либо константным членом класса, либо свободной функцией для двух аргументов, оба которых являются ссылкой на константу.

В целом, Catch требует от Вас не совсем справедливо, т.к. не фреймворку решать, но это, на самом деле, правильно реализовывать оператор сравнения либо как константный, либо как свободную функцию (второе предпочтительно, хотя в данном случае и не принципиально). Т.е. минимальные изменения, чтобы заставить этот код работать будут такими:

```
bool ComplexNum::operator == (const ComplexNum &comp) const {

    return this->re == comp.re && this->im == comp.im;
}
```

---

На будущее: приводите всю релеватную информацию в вопросе и не скриншотами. Код, текст ошибок — всё, что помогает людям понять Вашу проблему.

Comment: Спасибо большое, я только начинаю изучать c++. Вы мне очень помогли

Comment: @Пользователь, тогда нажмите галочку рядом с ответом.